# Xdebug not stopping at breakpoints when using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, visual-studio-code, xdebug

Let me just start with what I am using:

- PHP 7.3.25
- VSCode 1.52.1
- Xdebug See description

So let me explain the issue... I've been debugging with Xdebug for a while now. It has always served me well, unless it was about ajax calls. Sometimes when I call a PHP script with Ajax my Xdebug just stops working...
I keep seeing 2 requests running in the call stack tab:

[image]

I've tried updating my Xdebugging running 100 different settings but nothing will work...

Right now my php.ini is this:

[image]

And my launch.json is this:

[image]

This is my ajax call:

```
var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("projectId", id);
  formData.append("ajaxAction", "getProjectData");
  sendAjax(formData, (data) => {
    const json = JSON.parse(data);
    updateProject(json);
  });
```

```
function sendAjax(formData, cb) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    url: $("#url").val() + "Ajax",
    success: cb,
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
      alert("ajaxerror: " + jqXHR.responseText);
    },
  });
}
```

If anyone knows the solution ur an absolute god. I've visited over 100 sites and put a total of 3 days into this trying to fix it.

**UPDATE**
This is the day after I posted this. I found it the bug is because of something in the code itself... When I switched to another branch in GitHub my Xdebug worked fine but when I switched back to the master branch everything stopped working... I checked everything and compared it to my old code, I cannot find the issue.

My quest now is actually, where do I look?

Comment: If this works on switching branches, what is the exact difference?

Comment: That I cannot answer... The branch has been deleted by my colleague

Comment: Check your Xdebug log -- do you actually see a 2nd request? There will be one for main page, another is for your iframe. Although it could be much more of them (e.g. if you have requests to invalid resources and your 404 PHP handler kicks is (e.g. missing favicon.ico or alike)). P.S. Clear the log as needed before checking it (to avoid unrelated sessions).

Comment: My logs are empty...

Comment: 1) Wrong path 2) File access permissions 3) It actually does not debug (in your case -- maybe it's a different version). Post whole Xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output (or `xdebug_info()`) captured in the same way as you are trying to debug (a web page or CLI -- it's important).

Comment: 1) check 2) checked 3)https://1drv.ms/u/s!Asa5ffJ14caxjY1ey7UYnpv6gnBF7Q?e=rwYhoF
Thanks for the help my friend!

Comment: @Myrras were you able to fix this?

Comment: Yes I was able to fix it. Sorry I wasn't logged in... I changed the ports to 9003